# sonar option in right click not available

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

I am not able to see sonar option while right clicking on my project see image [image]

I am following this [docs to configure](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+in+Eclipse)

Everything else is running fine, only I am not able to see any of the options for my plugins like PMD, sonar etc. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option available called "Associate with Sonar". Basically you first need to associate your project with the remote sonar server to get the template. Once you do that, then you will be able to run the Sonar analysis locally on your eclipse.

Comment: I have already clicked on associate with sonar but still I am not getting it :(